# issue in making cross domain Ajax call to SharePoint 2016 REST service

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis7, cross-domain

To Fix issue in making cross domain Ajax call to SharePoint2016 REST service and

I dont want to set to the current specific (protocol + domain + port dynamically), because i need to accept by domain(mydomain.com) like the regular expression.

```
^(https?://(?:.+\.)?mywebsite\.com(?::\d{1,5})?)$
```

So,I used this technet.microsoft blog :[blog from microsoft](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2017/06/10/fixing-issue-in-making-cross-domain-ajax-call-to-sharepoint-rest-service-in-chrome/),on chrome and fireFox , I always get the error:

> Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers are not allowed for CORS
>   response.

So,on IIS, I follwed this  :
[SharePoint 2016 ,403 forbidden error](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/spmb/2018/06/27/sharepoint-2016-cors-javascript-csom-not-loading/)

end the error is :

> chrome:
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://dev1.mydomain.com/_api/web/AllProperties'
>   from origin 'https://dev2.maydomain.com' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   has a value 'https://mydomain.com' that is not equal to
>   the supplied origin.
>
> IE:  XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

JS script :

```
function getOSSSiteTitle(siteUrl) {

    var url = siteUrl + "/_api/web/AllProperties";
        console.log(url);
         return executeJson(url).then(
             function (data) {
                 return siteTitle = data.d.sitetitlelabelkey

        });
}



function executeJson(url, method, headers, payload, xhrFields) {
    method = method || 'GET';
    headers = headers || {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    headers["Content-Type"] = "'application/json;odata=verbose'";    
    headers["crossDomain"] = "true";
    headers["credentials"] = "include";
    //headers["X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED"] = "f";


    if (method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }
    var ajaxOptions = {
        url: url,
        type: method,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: headers
    };
    if (typeof payload != 'undefined') {
        ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

WebConfig:

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>      
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    <add name="X-MS-InvokeApp" value="1; RequireReadOnly" />        
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://mydomain.com" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Accept,X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED,crossDomain,credentials" />                                                     
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />                
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Note:
-and i add the iis rewrite module like blog,
-the public URL for the zone is added as https, the SP servers in IIS is binding for https port 443 and an SSL certificate.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the solution with you ,
i followed this blog :
 [Configure CORS for SharePoint 2016 (v 1.1)](https://support.communardo.de/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=67635639)
and changed the    by  by : `^(https?://.+\.mydomain.com(?::\d{1,5})?)$`